# How to add AVR support to Clang?

Tags: clang, llvm, avr

At the moment `LLVM` does not have `AVR` target and [this fork](https://github.com/dylanmckay/llvm) is created to add AVR backend/target. It seems to be ready to compile LLVM bitcode to AVR assembly. But `Clang` does not support AVR target (it does not support AVR attributes like 'progmem' and data layout). How can i add AVR support to Clang? I need guide [like that](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html) and i understand i need AVR knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created [clang fork](https://github.com/4ntoine/clang/tree/avr-support) to add AVR support. Feel free to join it and contribute.